# How to fill DataGridView with Strings/Ints in C++/CLI?

Tags: c++, windows-forms-designer

I need to fill a DataGridView in **C++** with a few values stored in a Vector.
However, when I attempt to add an int, it does not display.

```
        employeeDataGridView1->ColumnHeadersVisible = true;
        employeeDataGridView1->Columns[0]->Name = "ID";
        employeeDataGridView1->Columns[1]->Name = "Last Name";

    
        for (int i = 0; i < employees.size(); i++)
        {
            employeeDataGridView1->Rows->Add(employees[i].ID); //This is an int
        }
```

If I attempt to add an std::string it does not compile due to a lack of an overloaded constructor for std::strings.

```
        {
            employeeDataGridView1->Rows->Add(employees[i].fName); //This is an std::string
        }
```

If I simply hardcode text, it both compiles and shows the values.

```
for (int i = 0; i < employees.size(); i++)
        {
            employeeDataGridView1->Rows->Add("hey");// "hey" is a const char[4] NOT a const* char[4] which is why using c_str() throws the same compiler error as the string case. 
        }
```

Any ideas how to solve the above problems? I would need to display a few ints and strings. The employees vector is populated through a file which stores the data I need.
I am currently storing employee data as strings and ints.
If I have to, would it be faster to convert a string to const char[] or just get the data from the employee file directly as const char[]?

From what I've seen, C++/CLI is pretty much dead and I'm better off porting the project to Windows Desktop or C# forms.

Comment: C++/CLI ships with a `marshal_as` template which can be used to do this string conversion using syntax similar to a cast, if you include its header files.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think that

```
for (int i = 0; i < employees.size(); i++)
    {
        employeeDataGridView1->Rows->Add(employees[i].ID); //This is an int
    }
```

can be replaced by

```
employeeDataGridView1->Rows->Add(employees.size());
```

where employees.size() is the number of new row added.

You can find more information here : [Microsoft help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrowcollection.add?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#system-windows-forms-datagridviewrowcollection-add(system-int32))